# How to know if the video reached the last position when using video_player in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using video_player for displaying a video. I want to know the if the video reached the last position to display a replay icon and do some logic. How can we approach this in flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_videoController.addListener(() {                       //custom Listner
      setState(() {
        if (!_videoController.value.isPlaying &&_videoController.value.initialized &&
            (_videoController.value.duration ==_videoController.value.position)) { //checking the duration and position every time
          //Video Completed//
          // code here to show reply button//
        }
      });
    })
```

Comment: use a listener on your video controller and check for the current duration is equal to the total duration will give you the idea of the video finished.